# List of list with variable size of element with no brackets and apostrophes

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to make list of list, like in 1 element of new list should be variable size of elements of another list.

For exmaple:

```
Input buffor[]:

> "0,70"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,0"
> 
> ,"0,70"
> 
> ...
> 
> ,"n"
```

variable size, for example = 14 => list[0] = 14 elements of another list

```
(list[0] - list[13]) with no [] or ' between elements 

Output list[]:

> list[0] = "0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0"
> 
> ...
> 
> list[n] = ...
```

I got this line:

```
values = [values[i:i + size] for i in range(0, len(values), size)]
```

, but it is producing something like this:

```
> ['"val1"', ',"val2"', ... ,',"val13"']
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me at the moment..

Comment: What's a `buffor`?

Comment: `"0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0","0,0"` is not a list, it's a tuple.  Don't call a variable `list`, it masks the standard function of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Task is parsing html file, and proccesing to csv format printed in stdout.

Code:

```
> #!/usr/bin/python3
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
> #regex import re
> #argv from sys import argv
> #stdin from sys import stdin
> #csv import csv  
> #variable length of argv argvLen = len(argv)  
> #args
> #1 file if ( (argvLen > 1 ) and (argvLen < 3 ) ):
>     filename = argv[1]
>     with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
>         html = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')  
> #2 files dodać try catch elif (argvLen == 3):
>     filename = argv[1]
>     filename2 = argv[2]
>     with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
>         html = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
>     with open(filename2, 'r') as myfile:
>         users_list = [val.strip() for val in myfile]  
> #no files elif ( (argvLen == 1) or (argvLen > 4) ):
>     print("Required 1 or 2 parameters![FILE NAME1 - FILE NAME2].\n")
>     exit(0) #or quit()  
> #separating <table></table> from html file regex = r'<table width="100%" class="problems">([\S\s]*?)<\/table>' table =
> re.search(regex, html) if table:
>     print("Done. Seperate <table>\n")
>     table = table.group(1) else:
>     print("Error. No match <table>!\n")  
> #getting names regex = r'<th>(\S*?)<\/th>' names = re.findall(regex, table) if names:
>     print("Done. Names.\n") else:
>     print("Error. No match names!\n")  
> #getting kinds regex = r'\/problems\/[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/a>' comp = re.findall(regex, table) if comp:
>     print("Done. Kinds.\n") else:
>     print("Error. No match kinds!\n")  
> #size of comp size = len(comp)  
> #competitions + final score size += 1   print("Size: " + str(size) + "\n")  
> #getting users regex = r'\/users\/[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/a>' users = re.findall(regex, table) if users:
>     print("Done. Users.\n") else:
>     print("Error. No match users!\n")  
> #getting nicknames regex = r"\/users\/([\S]*?)'" nicks = re.findall(regex, table) if nicks:
>     print("Done. Nicks.\n") else:
>     print("Error. No match nicks!\n")  
> #getting values regex = r'<(?:font|td)[^>]*>(\d+(?:\.\d+)|-)' values = re.findall(regex, table) if values:
>     print("Done. Values.\n") else:
>     print("Error. No match values!\n")  
> #replace "-" to "0.0" values = [val.replace('-', '0.0') for val in values]  
> #replace "." to "," values = [val.replace('.', ',') for val in values]
>    
> #Editing Data for i in range(len(names)):
>     names[i] = '"' + names[i] + '"'
>     for i in range(len(values)):
>     values[i] = '"' + values[i] + '"'   for i in range(len(comp)):
>     comp[i] = '"' + comp[i] + '"'   if 'users_list' in globals():
>     for i in range(len(users_list)):
>         users_list[i] = '"' + users_list[i] + '"'   t1 = [] for i in range(len(comp)):
>     if i == 0:
>         t1 = comp[0]
>         continue
>     t1 += "," + comp[i]
>     for i in range(len(values)):
>     if ( (i % size) == 0 ):
>         continue
>     values[i] = "," + values[i]  
> #print for en in values:
>     print(str(en))  
> #TODO
> #here łaczenie values = [values[i:i + size] for i in range(0, len(values), size)]  
> #editing nick for i in range(len(users)):
>     #if name == null then name = nickname
>     if not users[i]:
>             users[i] = nicks[i]
>     #add " " - csv format
>     users[i] = '"' + users[i] + '"'
>     nicks[i] = '"' + nicks[i] + '"'
>    
> #First Row of CSV csvtable = [] csvtable.append(names[1] + ',' + '"NICK"' + ',' + t1 + ',' + names[3])  
> #Rest Data of CSV for i in range(len(users)):
>     #checking if name is on list
>     if 'users_list' in globals():
>         for check in users_list:
>             if(users[i-1] == check ):
>                 csvtable.append(users[i-1] + ',' + nicks[i-1] + ',' + str(values[i-1])[1:-1])
>  
>     else:
>         csvtable.append(users[i-1] + ',' + nicks[i-1] + ',' + str(values[i-1])[1:-1])
>    
> #printing csv file
> #for csv in csvtable:
> #   print(csv)
```

This is html file to parsing:

https://pastebin.com/waE7yrr0

And here is output what i looking for:

> "NAME","NICK","WIPING40","WIPING41","WIPING42","WIPING43","WIPING44","WIPING45","WIPING46","WIPING47","WIPING48","WIPING49","WIPING4A","WIPING4B1","WIPING4C","SCORE"
>
> "Marcel
> Rzepka","other019","1,00","2,00","2,00","2,00","3,00","4,00","4,00","2,00","2,00","4,00","3,00","4,00","7,00","40,00"
>
> "vaaadus","dtoton","1,00","2,00","2,00","2,00","3,00","4,00","4,00","2,00","2,00","4,00","3,00","4,00","7,00","40,00"
>
> "Zuzanna Zelek","zuza98","1,00","2,00","2,00","2,00","2,70","4,00","4,00","2,00","2,00","4,00","3,00","4,00","7,00","39,70"
>
> "Paweł Redman","theinvsblman","1,00","2,00","2,00","2,00","3,00","4,00","3,20","1,80","2,00","4,00","3,00","4,00","7,00","39,00"
>
> . . . .

I dont know python good, maybe there is a better solution of this problem.
All regexes are fine.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for solution

1 Simple While Loop

```
oper = 0
tmp = []
while (oper < len(values)):
    if ( (oper % size) == 0 ):
        temp = ''.join(map(str, values[oper:(size + oper)]))
        tmp.append(temp)
        oper += size
```

2 - using List comprehension:

```
values = [''.join(map(str, values[i:i + size])) for i in range(0, len(values), size)]
```